# How to build real time notifications in a distributed project?

Tags: websocket, push-notification, notifications, real-time, distributed

I wonder to know which technique and tools I should use to have the ability to send real time notifications to users. Specifically if I build a messaging system.

I can see that modern social networks can send notifications about new messages almost immediately. Even when the user 'A' from one country writes a message to the user 'B' in another country you can see that the user 'A' writes a message and you immediately see it (even if those users live in different continents). 
I tried to figure out how it is possible and find any information about this but without success. 
The only thing I found out is the technique when we use a Redis or RabbitMQ server with several servers which acts like publishers and subscribers. Our API servers receive new messages then they push a new message in the queue then subscribers receives the messages and if they have an open WebSocket with the recipient they push this message in the WebSocket and a client receives the message.

But it really won't work if you have a distributed project and your clients are connected to the nearest servers in the nearest data center.

The question is: what technologies/techniques/anything we should use to be able to build notifications in a distributed project?

Answer (score 0):

If you develop your distributed app/system using web technologies, you can consider building what is referred to as a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/). With PWAs you can add [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/push-notifications/) in a relatively easy way. You could start with a PWA approach, and then decide later on if developing a native app as well (i.e. iOS or Android) would be necessary.

There are many resources to learn and guide you in developing progressive web apps. Check the references I mentioned above, and you can do this [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/#0) as a starting point.